# How to upload an audio stream to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, web-audio-api

I am getting an audio stream from my devices microphone and want to upload the stream to my Node server.

I am getting my audio input as a stream like so:

```
const constraints = { 
  video: false, 
  audio: {deviceId: this.state.deviceId ? {exact: this.state.deviceId} : undefined},
};

window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => this.handleStream(stream))
  .catch(err => this.handleError(err))
```

As the user is speaking, I want to be uploading the stream to my node server.

Do I need to use some sort of websocket connection in order to upload a continuous stream or can I do it with an HTTP request, utilising axios or a similiar http request library?

Comment: Can you even get the media stream data in chunks while it's playing? There's [MediaRecorder.ondataavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable), but that only gets fired after the you stop recording.

Comment: @AndrewMyers are you saying the output of getUserMedia is not streamable? What about this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/microphone-stream? It has the function `micStream.on('data', function(chunk) {}` which appears to get Buffers which I would have thought is streamable?

Comment: I was saying _I_ couldn't find a way to make it streamable... So that library uses [BaseAudioContext.createScriptProcessor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createScriptProcessor), which is precisely what is necessary (for getting the data for a stream) and what I couldn't find.

Comment: Yeah I see. `createScriptProcessor()` seems to be the way to do it. I am just exploring with it now and think I have a working solution. Will post an update when it's working